# How do I determine which build command to use when hosting my web app?

Tags: visual-studio-code, build, web-applications, hosting

So I've created my very first web app using VSCode, node.js, express, mustache and MongoDB. I now intend on hosting the app using AWS Amplify, but it's asking for a 'build command'. I use the command 'nodemon --ext js,mustache index' to view my app on a local server - that's not the command I provide Amplify with, is it? (Sorry for the noob questions)

I read elsewhere that I should look in my package.json file within my project, but that doesn't mention any build commands:

```
{
  "name": "<name>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "<author>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^5.5.0",
    "mustache-express": "^1.3.2",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you even _need_ a build command?